# How to parse XML data as string instead of dictionary using Python XML ElementTree library

Tags: python, xml, string, dictionary

'I want to parse an XML file using the Python XML ElementTree library.

XML data example:

```
<stat pass="2" fail="1" skip="0" id="s1-s2" name="Webview">Test passed</stat>
```

I would like to parse the XML data in the exact format as in the XML file and store as a Python string, so:

```
string = '<stat pass="2" fail="1" skip="0" id="s1-s2" name="Bankwebview">Test passed</stat>'
```

At the moment, I have only came across the .attrib method and .text method which gives me the following format:

```
def extract_testcase(xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    #Get root <robot> data
    root_att = root.attrib    # {'pass':'2', 'fail':'1', 'skip':'0', 'id'='s1-s2', 'name'='Webview'}
    root_text = root.text     # 'Test passed'
```

In which I will need to manipulate the data again to get my desired string.
Is there a function in ElementTree for my intended output?

Comment: `root.attrib['name'] ='BankWebview'`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to *read* the XML into a string, without really parsing it. You could do it with a regular file access in Python:

```
with open("my_file.xml", "r") as my_input_xml:
    my_string = my_input_xml.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of an attribute there is a function `Element.get('name')` in `xml.etree.ElementTree`.
You can use `Element.set('name','value')` to manipulate the attribute value of a XML byte Element ([Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """<stat pass="2" fail="1" skip="0" id="s1-s2" name="Webview">Test passed</stat>"""

def extract_testcase(xml_string):
    x_st = ET.fromstring(xml)
    x_st.set('name', 'Bankwebview')
    return ET.tostring(x_st).decode('utf-8')
    
print("Input string: ", xml)
xml_new = extract_testcase(xml)
print("Output string",xml_new)
```

Print:

```
Input string:  <stat pass="2" fail="1" skip="0" id="s1-s2" name="Webview">Test passed</stat>
Output string: <stat pass="2" fail="1" skip="0" id="s1-s2" name="Bankwebview">Test passed</stat>
```